# Eclipse/Subclipse skip Team submenu

Tags: svn, eclipse, context-menu, subclipse

I am working in Eclipse Kepler on an Android project and all files are version controlled by Subversion. In Eclipse I have Subclipse installed and it works well.

If I want to commit or update a file I have to right click in the Eclipse project explorer on the file, open the submenu `Team` and then click either Commit or Update. I want to skip this annoying submenu Team and just have to right click the file and click Commit immediately. Is this possible? Maybe by using a plugin?

The image below shows the problem. I just want a few of the menu items like Commit, Update, Merge and Revert in the top-level menu, below Copy, Paste and Delete.
[image: The Subclipse menu]

Comment: Same problem here.  +1